# Jquery css borderLeft on mouseover move the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with the function css of jquery.

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
                  $(this).css( {borderLeft: '6px solid green'});

              });
```

It work, the borderLeft appear on the element. The problem is the element move (6px to the left)

I tried :

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
                  $(this).css( {borderLeft: '6px solid green', margin: '-6px' });

              });
```

The element still move, I tried also :

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {

                  $(this).css( {borderLeft: '6px solid green', marginLeft: '-6px' });

              });
```

Same problem.

How can I spawn the borderLeft on my element without moving anything ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider using `addClass` and making all the changes from the css file, instead of using the jQuery `css` method to add them inline. It's much more cleaner and a lot easier to overwrite or remove them in the future, instead of using important or going trought the js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use transparent border, and you can do it without javascript, just CSS:

```
.myClass { border-left: 6px solid transparent; }
.myClass:hover { border-left: 6px solid green; }
```

UPD: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c531rmg6/) is an example

Answer (score 3):

Borders normally adds to the dimension of the element, so it pushes your element more to right.
You should add `box-sizing: border-box` .

```
.myClass{
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

The reason this will work is, as per the [**box-sizing MDN documentation**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), setting `box-sizing` to `border-box` causes the `width` and `height` properties to include the `padding` and `border`.

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrqpwqge/) - Using `border-box`

---

Comment: @Anyone_ph: It won't work in IE7 or lower. Might need browser prefix as well, i.e: `-webkit`, `-moz`, etc... Works without prefix in Chrome. Have a look and see if this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rrqpwqge/) works for you

Comment: Your demo doesn't work on Firefox 24.7.0 but I gave a try with Google chrome and indeed, it's working without problem on this browser.

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, define a 6px border for the element, and on hover just change the border color of the element, which in this case it looks like that you apply a border on hover.

```
.myClass{
    border: 6px solid [colorOftheBackground]; 
}
```

On the other hand, you can just do this without jQuery.

```
.myClass{
    border: 6px solid [colorOftheBackground]; 
}

.myClass:hover{
    border-color: green; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It happened because your default element don't have border. Put border in your css with that background color.

In jQuery like this

```
$('.myClass').css( {borderLeft: '6px solid default-color'});
```

Or in css

```
    .myClass{
       border: 6px solid [colorOftheBackground]; 
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Add the margin-left directly in css.

```
.myClass { margin-left: 6px; }
```

Then remove it in jQuery.

```
$('.myClass').mouseover(function() {
$(this).css( {borderLeft: '6px solid green', marginLeft: 0' });
});
```

You can check it on [jdfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bzvawwdy/).